# change ID number format of number to date format

Tags: sql-server

I would like to write an ID number from this format YYMMDDXXXXXXX to this 19YY-MM-DD or 20YY-MM-DD in sql.

```
select Customer_identifier from  MartDB.DBO.BAW_AllSources_Stage1_202005
```

Customer_identifier cexample is 8801213535353 where 88 represents year of birth 1988, 01 represents month of birth January, 21 represents day of birth the 21st.  21 Jan 1988.  I want to convert that to a date 1988-01-21

Comment: So what is stopping you? What have *you* tried? If someone has the value `'0903063424643'` how do **you** know if that's 2009 or 1909?

Answer (score 0):

Below the script but work only with born date <2000 because you have a design problem

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('19'+ SUBSTRING(CAST(8801213535353 AS varchar(13)), 1, 6) AS date)
```

I used TRY_CAST because return a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds, otherwise, returns null.

You can also format the date in a different way using FORMAT function (from SQL Server 2012).

Some example:

```
SELECT  FORMAT(TRY_CAST('19'+ SUBSTRING(CAST(8801213535353 AS varchar(13)), 1, 6) AS date), 'yyyy-MMMM-dd')
```

The output is: **1988-January-21**

Example with culture parameter:

```
SELECT  FORMAT(TRY_CAST('19'+ SUBSTRING(CAST(8801213535353 AS varchar(13)), 1, 6) AS date), 'D', 'En-Us')
```

The output is: **Thursday, January 21, 1988**

Comment: This assumes no one is born on or after 01 January 2020 though. I can assure you, there have been millions of people born in the last 20 years.

Comment: Any news about it?